# Automatic payment with paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I am developing a web site using php and symfony framework. I would like to know if its possible to transfer money from my paypal account to another paypal account through my website. I would like to write the amount money in a input and the paypal account in another input and transfer that amount to the written paypal account FROM MY paypal account. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Anything is possible using the [PayPal API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/). I'd suggest trying it out and coming back here to ask specific questions about specific parts that you're having problems with. Tl;dr - we don't deal with **hypotheticals**

Comment: thank you very much. I decide to ask this question becouse I called Paypal and they told me I can't do this... But I thought... impossible!! So for this reason I decided to write this. Thank you very much! :) So, do you confirm this?

Comment: Do I confirm what? Have a read through the API and check it out yourself. If you've phoned PayPal and they've said it's not possible then that probably means it is possible, but **against their terms and conditions** or it could mean that it just simply isn't technically possible. I'd recommend following PayPal's advice on this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirments, you may try to use Payout APIs to send your money to any email address or US mobile phone. However, merchants in the United States can register to use Payouts in the Live environment. Other merchants should contact their Account Manager or Paypal customer service to enable Payouts.
Add the Paypal official document for your reference, [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/).